# a hashing algorithm that only can compares with its original

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash, cryptography

Is there any algorithm to hash an array of bytes that for the same input generates multiple random secure hashes WITHOUT ability to compare hashes with each other at all and only we can compare each hash with the original bytes?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Rather than asking us about the solution you think you need, edit your question to tell us what the actual problem you're trying to solve is.  Until then, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, so voting to close.

Comment: so I'm looking for a hash function with that property, what's wrong?

Comment: Please read my comment in detail, or, if you don't understand, read about what an XY problem is. *Why* are you looking for a hashing algorithm with that property? Chances are there is an easier way to solve your problem - your current question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What you are describing is an nondeterministic algorithm. Now nondeterminism is of course possible given a random value such as a salt. However, usually we consider the salt as part of the input though. Computers / algorithms are otherwise deterministic : given a certain input and state, they will always calculate the same output. So with these definitions, the answer is *no*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a "salt" for that kind of use case.

A salt is a unique/random value you generate before you hash.  Then instead  of recording just `hash(bytes)`, you record `(salt, hash(salt+bytes))`.

If you know the original bytes, you can verify that they match the salted hash, but you *can't* compare two salted hashes to see if they were generated by the same byte array.  Of course every salted hash you generate has to have a unique salt to make that work.

This is used to prevent 'dictionary attacks' that match a list of hashed passwords against a dictionary of known hashes.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)